# Getting the next specified element in lxml?

Tags: python, html, lxml

I'm struggling trying to parse this html. There are h2s acting as titles for paragraphs. Both are in separate divs, and separated by more divs. The paragraph isn't a child of the h2. I'd like to group them together, but I can't figure how out. I thought find would do it but it didn't work:

```
html = doc.cssselect('h2.title')
for para in html:
  content = para.find('div.content')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Submitting a fragment of the HTML will make things easier for people answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

`lxml.html.HtmlElement.find` only takes a tag name or a path - it doesn't accept full  CSS selectors.

A better idea would just be to use `doc.cssselect` with advanced selectors. `lxml.html` will convert them to XPath selectors for you.

Perhaps:

```
for elem in doc.cssselect('h2.title div.content'):
    elem.text_content()
```